# API has redirecting page - PHP

Tags: php, api

I need to send data to an API using PHP. The API has a redirect page before showing the final result. The following code shows the content of the redirecting page rather than the final result. How can I wait until the final result?

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api';
$data = array('text' => "try");

$options = array(
   'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

echo $result;
```

P.S. I got this code from one of stackoverflow's questions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "redirect"? Does the page return 3xx HTTP status code?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I mean when I go to the API url (for example, https://example.com/api?text=try) with my browser, it first shows a redirecting page (e.g. wait until the process is finished...) and then it shows the final result that is a file. My code shows the html source code of the first page.

Comment: It may be that javascript is being used to redirect the browser rather than an actual http redirect. If it's javascript, maybe you could read the newer destination and then update your API call to just go direct to the final destination?

Comment: @GreensterRox The final destination's URL is the same as the first one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [cURL](https://php.net/curl_init) to get the final response, using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`:

From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) :

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION: TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api';
$data = array('text' => "try");

$full_url = $url . (strpos($url, '?') === FALSE ? '?' : '') 
            . http_build_query($data) ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $full_url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
     'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($response) ;
```

Comment: I tried this code but I got again the redirecting page's HTML code.

Comment: Maybe the redirection is done in JavaScript. What is the HTTP code and headers of the redirecting page?

Comment: Yes. I checked this. The redirection is using JavaScript.

Comment: So you cannot do this using PHP in one time... You have to get the first page, parse and detect URL, then make a new request. Because PHP doesn't interpret the JavaScript.

Comment: https://github.com/aslushnikov/latex-online#api. This is the webpage of the API. HTTP code is 200.